# How to send post data with ajax request though Datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I have been trying to send some post data with ajax request to server through datatables ,following is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //this is the datatable it brings data in json format from server
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var selected = $("#mainschool_id option:selected").val();
        //alert(selected);
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/nvs/system/modules/NVS.NLI/elements/trainingalldatatable.jsp",
                "data": {
                    data: selected
                }

            },
            "sAjaxSource": "/nvs/system/modules/NVS.NLI/elements/trainingalldatatable.jsp",
            "search": {
                "smart": false
            },
            "scrollX": true,
            "aoColumns": [{
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "number"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                },
                {
                    type: "text"
                }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it is throwing ajax error ,every time i am using .There is no specific explaination for using datatables with jsp and java.Any help would be really appreciated .Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: After looking at the code, I seem to notice this is actually Javascript and not Java, Might want to get that fixed :)

Comment: it gives an alert .Ajax error contact datables.net

Comment: @Rab yes rectified ,removed the tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As your are using two urls one from Sajaxsource and othe inside ajax ,you dont have to use ajaxsource in this case

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//this is the datatable it brings data in json format from server
$( document ).ready(function() {
var selected=$("#mainschool_id option:selected").val();
//alert(selected);
$('#example').dataTable({
       "bProcessing": true,
             "ajax": {
            "url": "/nvs/system/modules/NVS.NLI/elements/trainingalldatatable.jsp",
            "data":{data:selected}

            },

               "search": {
                 "smart": false
               },
               "scrollX": true,
       "aoColumns": [
           { type: "text"},
           { type: "number"},
           { type: "text" },
           { type: "text" },
           { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" },
                       {type:"text"},
                       { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" },
                       {type:"text"},
                        {type:"text"}



              ]
      });
});
</script>
```

I hope it helps thanks.